# Implementing multi user chat in iPad App

Tags: ios, websocket, xmpp, chat

I have an iPad app. I'm planning to add a group chat feature to it. This means 1)users can create or join a group
2)Can text or send audio clips to other users logged into the app.

I'm looking for pointers on how to go about implementing this. I read numerous articles. I have narrowed down to
1) XMPP (Jabber) and
2) WebSocket
based solutions.

I have experience in iOS , but am new to other technologies. What would be a good approach ? Are there any free libraries or SDK's available which would help me as i do not want to go about building everything from scratch and have limited time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not implement all of that on my own nor host the service myself.

You should think about using an existing system for this.

(I am not in any way affiliated with the next suggestions)

I have used:

[firebase.com](http://firebase.com)

and

[parse.com](http://parse.com)

Both should work for your usecase, but firebase is actually made for this!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  Nils , but both firebase and parse are paid solutions. Are there any free alternatives

Comment: You don't have to pay for parse! They have a very large 'free tier'

Comment: 30 requests per second and 1000000 push notifications per month are free

Comment: OK. Will research that further. I would be grateful if you could point me to any tutorials that would help me . I am currently reading through http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958

Comment: ok . Do you have any suggestions about http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: Only that you should probably use this framework on iOS https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80809/discussion-between-mithun-madhav-and-nils-ziehn).

Comment: Parse and Firebase support push notifications, but for true chat solution, you need to have a real server. In iOS for example, while the device is turn off, only one message is kept by Apple. If you receive more, you will simply lose messages.

Comment: Firebase and Parse store the messages for you.

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases, you will need Backend server. In case of third party services almost all are paid one but they provide some Free usage like

https://quickblox.com/

https://www.pubnub.com/ - http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/

https://tokbox.com/platform